# Creating custom mouseover in angular and passing $event to directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

Heres my directive called `tooltip`:

```
.directive('tooltip', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.enter = function(evt) {
          console.log('x: ' + evt.x + ', y: ' + evt.y);
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
        scope.$apply(attrs.tooltip);
      });

    }
}
```

});

**HTML:**

```
<svg>
  <g pathing tooltip="enter($event)">
   ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed in via `attrs.tooltip` cannot be called directly like that.

You have to use the `$parse` service to invoke the function like this:

```
.directive('tooltip', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.enter = function(evt) {
        console.log('x: ' + evt.x + ', y: ' + evt.y);
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs.tooltip);
      element.bind("mouseenter", function(event) {
        fn(scope, { $event: event });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

But, even better than that, why don't you just use the `ng-mouseover` directive

```
<g pathing ng-mouseover="enter($event)">
...
</g>
```

**Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hh0OCDWsRhYWcyhjvGiD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the `mouseenter` event to the function.

This should work

```
element.bind("mouseenter", function(event) {
    scope.$apply(function(){
         attrs.tooltip(event);
     });
  });
```

Not sure why you don't just use call from scope:

```
$scope.enter(event)
```

Comment: The first snippet doesn't work, it throw an `TypeError: string is not a function` exception because the `attrs.tooltip` is just a string not a function.

Comment: @runTarm makes sense , that's why i suggested just calling it from scope. Could be passed as string to attribute `tooltip="event"` then call `$scope[attrs.tooltip](event)`

Comment: Yes, that will works in this case. But by using `$parse`, it also support a scenario that the directive has an isolated scope and the `enter()` function is defined in an controller outside. However, lets just use the `ng-mouseover` :)